# Composite primary keys and link table rules

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a many to many relationship with a link table and I need to formalise a rule set. Following is my problem:

Left (L) and Right (R) (L&R) Table: both have composite (thanks stakx for correcting me) primary keys. Link table has its own primary key but obviously, because the L&R tables have each composite primaries the link table must contain multiple foreign keys. No problem. i.e.

```
L Table:
LID       (int)      PK1
LSomeDate (DateTime) PK2
Other Fields...

R Table:
RID       (int)      PK1
RSomeDate (DateTime) PK2
Other Fields...

Link Table:
ID        (int)      PK
LID       (int)      FK1
LSomeDate (DateTime) FK1
RID       (int)      FK2
RSomeDate (DateTime) FK2
```

Requirement 1: An entity in either table can exist without the other. So instead of a 1:M we should have a 0:M on both sides of the M:M. I am guessing (perhaps wrongly) that this means I must leave the link table foreign keys null. But if I do this, I can enter say LID and leave the LSomeDate field null. or vice versa. Likewise with the RID and RSomeDate.

My first question is, what is the standard way to create some "whatever (rule, constraint, default, trigger etc)" that will force the user to enter an LID if a LSomeDate was entered or enter an LSomeDate if an LID was entered. I can then apply the same to the R FK. This will prevent leaving nulls in part of the FK.

Essentially...Either the whole L side of the FK is null, or both fields are filled (a valid ref). Likewise for the R but this would be separate.

My other question is...When creating link tables, should the L table contain a FKID of the right table and vice versa, for example...Should the L Table above also contain RID and RSomeDate as foreign keys, and vice versa on the R Table, or is the fact that these are specified in the link table enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note about terminology: While a table can have several candidate keys, they can have only one primary key. This primary key, however, may be a composite key (i.e. consist of more than one column). I assume you meant to say that both your L & R tables have a composite primary key?

Comment: What do you mean by saying, _"…force the user to enter a …ID"_? Is the user inserting directly into the database? That is, do you want to enforce this rule directly at the database level, or at the application level?

Comment: I am in the process of building the database, so I have not started app dev yet. My idea is, that as this is a database concern (as opposed to business logic), it should be handled by the db and if both are not correct the db should throw an error that can be caught at the app level. The user may not get to enter the data in the link table (hopefully), but I want to catch it here as it means less code and I feel it is a db concern to ensure the data is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for having an entry in the link table is to link one L record to another R record. If one L exists without being linked to any R, then there is an recird in L, but there will be no entry for this particular combination of L and R in the link table.

That is, an entry in the N:N link table exists only if an L and an R are associated. That is, if two records L and R are not linked ("one exists without the other"), then there simply won't be an entry in the link table. And therefore, there is never even the need for `NULL` values in the link table.

Meaning, ideally, all your link table columns are declared `NOT NULL`; and suddenly your problem goes away!

(This btw. has nothing to do with your primary keys being composite; the same fact would hold for non-composite keys.)

If you, despite this fact, still wanted to declare these columns `NULL`able, and you wanted to ensure, at the database level, that e.g. all L foreign keys in your link table are not partially `NULL`, you could add a `CHECK` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE LinkTable
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LinkTable_LID_LSomeDate
CHECK ((LID IS NULL     AND LSomeDate IS NULL    ) 
    OR (LID IS NOT NULL AND LSomeDate IS NOT NULL))
```

But again, it would be infinitely better if all of these foreign key columns were `NOT NULL`able in the first place, because that's how a N:N link table should be designed.

Comment: This makes perfect sense...I feel like a dummy now. Sorry. My head is foggy as I have multiple places where this is happening and I am trying to understand it all as it was done by a past dev. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers: No worries, mate. We're all here to learn. (Feel free to upvote or even accept the answer if you feel that it has been helpful. ;-)

Comment: So if I understand correctly. Forget the constraint, just don't allow the FK's in the link table to be null. This is because 0:N can be represented on either side by simply entering the record on the relevant side and not relating it through the link table. The link table is only needed when linking one side to the other...Is this right?

Comment: @FrancisRodgers: Exactly! (A link table implements the logical N:M relationship between two tables L and R as two relationships: 1:N between L and the link table, and 1:M between R and the link table. A properly designed link table never has 0:* or 0..1:* cardinalities to either side, only 1:*.)

Comment: Very cool rule dude...I removed the allow nulls as suggested and started getting all those errors that I wanted...The best thing was, no constraints or code needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just briefly when you are on again. There was a second part to my question relating to link tables. This being if I have the situation above (with or without compound primaries), do I actually need to put RId into the L table, and LID into the R table or is the fact that the ID fields are in the link table usually enough. Whats the standard here.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers: Regarding your 2nd question: No, the L table should not have a R FK in your case (and neither should the R table have an L FK). Having a link table only is the way to go when you're modelling an N:M relationship. A FK *always* models a *:1 relationship to the target table (or *:0..1 if the FK column(s) are `NULL`able), which is not what you want. (Btw. that is the reason why a link table decomposes a N:M relationship into two relationships 1:N and M:1; because it has two FKs.)